# Ограничение на ввод данных от пользователя в боте вк VkBottle на Python

Tags: python, бот

Делаю в вк бота, и хочу сделать ограничение на ввод данных. Например я пишу так -
/form /banoff 0 Test_Test 30 тест и бот это записывает в базу данных, и например если писать /form /banoff 0 0 0 00000020030494838382882828383 и так до бесконечности, он это все равно запишет в бд, как сделать ограничение на ввод данных? Например максимум чтобы можно было записать 30 символов, а в случае если он пишет больше 30 символов, чтобы ему выдавало типо: Вы вводите слишком большое сообщение! Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить хендлер, который будет реагировать на сообщения больше 30 символов:

```
@bot.on.message(length=30)
async def long_message_handler(message: Message):
    await message.reply("Слишком большое сообщение!")
```

где length=30 значит, что обрабатываться будут только сообщения длиной 30 и более символов. Главное поместить хендлер выше остальных.